# Is it possible to monitor Postgres DB access via Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, audit

For auditing purposes, my organization would love to monitor if anyone access the Postgres DB directly.

The majority of the time Postgres is accessed through actions in Rails or via the production `rails console` that lead engineers have access to.

But it is also possible to access the `psql` shell directly if one has the `DATABASE_URL` from Heroku.

We'd love to monitor if anyone actually does this. Is there an inbuilt way via Postgres that we can capture this. Or even better, does Heroku capture this?

Thanks!